# Populate a html form field with value from a form on another page

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have a form in Nodejs application.When the user clicks on the link near one of the fields,a pop up opens with another form. The value from the popup window is to be sent back to a field in the previous page.
Any clues on how i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.opener):

> Returns a reference to the window that opened this current window.